# Mysqljs, several queries in one query

Tags: node.js

Is there a way to perform a SQL query which consists of several queries?

Following example returns syntax error:

```
connection.query('UPDATE table1 SET field="1" WHERE id=1; UPDATE table1 SET field="2" WHERE id=2;'
,function(error, results, fields) {});
```

Comment: https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#multiple-statement-queries

Comment: @robertklep thanks! That solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

You may find that your MySQL package does not support multiple statement queries. It's not clear which MySQL package you are using (there are several out there). Some connectors in some languages do offer this ability (I'm thinking of PHP specifically), but I don't know if any of the node.js packages do.

However... this is not a good practice anyway. To see why, consider a whole list of queries run as one big long string:

```
connection.query(`
    UPDATE table1 SET field='a' WHERE id=1;
    UPDATE table1 SET field='b' WHERE id=2;
    UPDATE table1 SIT field='c' WHERE id=3;
    UPDATE table1 SET field='d' WHERE id=4;
    UPDATE table1 SET field='e' WHERE id=5;
`, function (err, results, fields) {});
```

This query is going to fail with a MySQL syntax error because I deliberately misspelled a keyword. But you're just going to get a single "syntax error" from the MySQL connector and it will be up to you to go through each of the queries trying to find the problem. For a simple error like this, it might not be too hard, but if you're building longer queries with complicated logic and concatenating them all into one long string, it's going to be very difficult to debug.

You may be trying to improve performance with this kind of thing, but any performance gain you get will be minor. You will save some time transferring the query to the database server (one big string instead of a bunch of individual ones), but the server is still going to have to execute each query one at a time.

TL;DR run your queries one at a time. It makes finding problems much easier and that will outweigh any performance benefit you might gain.

Comment: Sorry for confusion, syntax error appears even if **whole SQL is in one line**. It's not about backslash. The thing is that I need to perform number of updates, one after another, but I can't make it in separate queries, with callback for each query, because number of updates is not constant. I need to know when all queries are completed.

Comment: _"Node.js/Javascript does not permit strings to span several lines using the \ character"_. [Hmm?](https://davidwalsh.name/multiline-javascript-strings).

Comment: @robertklep Hmmm? indeed. I learned something new today. Thanks! I'll update my answer.

Comment: @Kryten unfortunately the issue was not in syntax at all, before posting the question I have launched several queries in one query and then single query. And it did not work in first case and worked in second case.